# All labels on Google Maps showing up as solid boxes. What could be going wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

[what I see when I use Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6zFo.png)

For some reason when I try to use Google Maps recently all the labels show up as solid boxes instead of as text. It makes the site unusable. I think this may have begun when I installed node.js to get some web project to run.

I am on Linux Mint 17.1 in Chrome. Firefox does not exhibit the same problem.

Comment: I have same issue in Chrome on Ubuntu and observe it for couple days. But I have not installed anything new recently. Only updated Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/maps/MZbt7_U-3u8/Di0d6tyFAAAJ) discussion at Google Product Forum. It seems that the recent Chrome update to version 54 (64 bit) for Linux users has some kind of internal bug. I believe, it is completely unrelated to your Node.js installation.

The discussion mentions the bug report has been already submitted to Google. See the forum for more details.